# Cannot change primary button color with LESS (ant.design)

Tags: css, reactjs, less

I have used ant design to get a primary button style however trying to change the background color of it with LESS and nothing works for some reason,could somebody maybe faced same problem or know the solution, i know i can do it easy way by doing style={{background-color}} however i do not want to write extra code when it is should be working with LESS. I am setting primary color for all tekst and it works just fine

```
@btn-primary-bg: #1B2F55;

  <Button type='primary' onClick={this.handleSubmitEmail}>{submit}</Button>
```

antd.customize.less

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGUoD.png)

Comment: Can you include your webpack config where you are including your style override?

Comment: @ageoff could not post a code so i have added a pic, thank you

Comment: That is your less file, but you must include it somewhere. https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme which option are you using to include your override less file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to access antd's button class to change the style.

Add a new class name to your button component.

```
 <Button type='primary' classname={'my-button'} onClick={this.handleSubmitEmail}>{submit}</Button>
```

Then, in LESS file, do this,

```
.ant-btn.my-button{
  background-color: 'red'
}
```

Comment: yeh thank you, i know i can do it that way but why cant i just use the @btn-primary-color to change the color
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less

Comment: Hey. Do you want to change using less file. If yes then you need to import that particular file in which you have `@btn-primary-color ` this constant. 

So you can do, 
`@import 'file_name.less'` and then do `.ant-btn.my-button{
  background-color: @btn-primary-color
}`

Let me know if this is what you are asking?

Comment: This doesn't cover the hover, it gets back to the default on focus and active states.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem , project was taken from another and app.css had ant primary with color set and because of that i found and learned about priorities

Comment: Same here. I had `@import '~antd/dist/antd.css'` at the top of my `App.css` file, and this was overriding the custom styles I had set.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<Button htmlType="button" type="primary" id="turf-button" disabled={bnstate} shape="round" size="small" onClick={onconnect}>`
then

```css
#turf-button {
  background-color: lime;
}
```